# SQL: inserting the correct field from the set into a sample

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple query that looks for duplicates by ext_id:

```
SELECT s.ext_id, count(s.ext_id), s.id
FROM sale_point AS s
GROUP BY s.ext_id
HAVING count(s.ext_id) > 1;
```

The problem is that it substitutes the first id found in place of s.id, but I need the last one found.

Please tell me how to place in field last id found?

Example:

I have a set of entries in mariaDB with fields like this:

```
+--------+------------+
| id     | ext_id     |
+--------+------------+
| 376764 | 2065277658 |
+--------+------------+
| 390836 | 2065277658 |
+--------+------------+
```

Result will be:

```
+------------+-----------------+--------+
| ext_id     | count(s.ext_id) | id     |
+------------+-----------------+--------+
| 2065277658 |               2 | 376764 |
+------------+-----------------+--------+
```

In this case, there shown first id in set (376764), but I need last (390836).

Comment: _last one found_, does that simply mean you want `max(s.id)`?

Comment: Please define what makes one `s.id` value the "last one found."  I am guessing that you are using MySQL here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*last one found*, does that simply mean you want max(s.id)?

```
SELECT s.ext_id, count(s.ext_id), max(s.id)
FROM sale_point AS s
GROUP BY s.ext_id
HAVING count(s.ext_id) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not make sense because you are grouping by `s.ext_id` and aggregating `s.ext_id`! 
You can do:

```
SELECT s.ext_id, count(s.id), max(s.id)
FROM sale_point AS s
GROUP BY s.ext_id
HAVING count(s.id) > 1;
```

which groups by `s.ext_id` and counts `s.id`.
It also returns the maximum value of `s.id`.